# Appending a changing variable jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I click on a button I get it to append html code. Within this html code I want it to have dynamic Id's. I have a count variable called `id_count` and I set it to 1 by saying `var id_count = 1;` and then when the button is clicked I add one to the `id_count` value. However, I have tried adding this in my appended code but it only takes the original value of `id_count`. So, if I click my button twice although the count will go up to 3 the variable in my append statement stays at 1.

I don't know why this is happening. I have looked at loads of other posts but none of them seem to help me, hence why I am writing this. Basically I want to have unqiue id's for all of my appended elements but I'm not sure how. Sorry is this is a duplicated question.

Here is my jquery code:

```
$j = $.noConflict();
var id_count = 1;
var id_sub = 1;
var htmlcode = "<div class='fieldset' id='fieldset_"+id_count+"'> <h2>Child Information</h2></div>";
$j(".btn-addchild").click(function(){
    id_count++;
    alert(id_count);
    $j(".child-info-content").append(htmlcode);
});
$j(".child-info-content").on('click','#removechild',function() {
    $j(this).parents('.fieldsetAdditional').slideUp("normal",function() {$j(this).parents('.fieldsetAdditional').remove();});
    id_count = id_count - id_sub;
    alert(id_count);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move definition of `htmlcode` into the function. When you place it outside the function, it will not be executed each time you execute the click function.

```
$j(".btn-addchild").click(function(){
    alert(id_count);
    var htmlcode = "<div class='fieldset' id='fieldset_" + id_count + "'> <h2>Child Information</h2></div>";
    $j(".child-info-content").append(htmlcode);
    id_count++;
});
```